# How to keep the server client connection on

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, server, client

I have used an existing node.js code to receive data from a GPS device. The code is functional but has one flaw.  Ideally we want to keep the server-client connection alive. But it appears the connection is closed and then is opened very frequently. When I run the following code, the output is like this

> > new connection
> >        existing connection
> >        existing connection
> >        new connection
> >        existing connection
> >        existing connection
> >        new connection

Any one has suggestions to change it? Ideally, we want to have only one new connection and then the rest is existing connections.

```
const net = require('net');
const request = require('request');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

console.log('new connection');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
data = data.toString();
console.log('data from port',data);

console.log('exiting connection');
});
}).listen(39003, '0.0.0.0');

server.on('error', (err) => {
console.log(err);
});

server.on('listening', () => {
console.log('listening on port ' + 39003);
});
```

Comment: Do you have client code?

Answer (score 0):

Two things / action items you need:

- Your code, has to have keep-alives enabled (take a look at this, for nodejs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/agentkeepalive).
- Remote code needs to be configured to honor keepalives (you can run tcpdump / wireshark to see which end closes the connection). Depending on what serves the GPS data, different configuration options are available. For example in nginx one would disable keepalives with `keepalive_timeout 0;` directive.